# Additional basketball qualification tournaments for 2020 Olympics

Tags: basketball, olympics

Helo! I would like to ask for some help in understanding how qualifications for Olympic men's basketball tournament at 2020 Olympics work.

Firstly, i know that there would be 12 teams at basketball's tournament. One of the places is reserved for the host nation's team, in this case Japan. Next seven places is going to be determined at the World Cup in the China next year:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basketball_at_the_2020_Summer_Olympics_–_Men%27s_qualification

I have a problem in understanding how additional wild card tournaments are structured. I know that the best 16 teams from World Cup that didn't qualified by the World Cup, will participate in these wild card tournaments. Now, things get a little bit more unclear, because of the following picture:

[image]

So, my question is next:

If it is going to be 4 wild card tournaments with 6 teams in each, how can they add additional 2 teams per FIBA region in addition to 16 teams from World Cup, because that gives the number of 26 teams?

Please, could anyone clarify this a little bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [2019 World Cup qualifying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_FIBA_Basketball_World_Cup_qualification), it looks like the Asia and Oceania regions are combined into one region, so there are only 4 regions for the purposes of the "+2 from each region" detail. So they take the best remaining 16 teams regardless of region, then the next best two teams from each region.

Comment: Thank you! I guess that's how they are going to decide additional 2 tems per region. The fact that at the World Cup, Asian and Oceanian places are separated, confused me, because they are one region in qualifiers.